# How to calculate a Delaunay mesh nerve?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

How to calculate a Delaunay mesh nerve? A Delaunay mesh nerve
is a collection of triangles that surround a single triangle called the nerve nucleus. The triangles in a Delaunay mesh nerve either have a common edge or a common vertex with the nerve nucleus. Here, nerve nucleus means that triangle which has maximum area in a Delaunay mesh.

Here is the code I developed to find the Delaunay mesh. But, I can't calculate the mesh nerve. Please kindly let me know. Thanks.

```
c = ImageCorners[img, MaxFeatures -> 200];
dm = DelaunayMesh[c];
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the concept of the "nerve" of a mesh, and a quick google search did not return anything pertinent. Could you perhaps point to a web site with a definition and a few examples.

Comment: A Delaunay mesh nerve is a collection of triangles that surround a single triangle called the nerve nucleus. The triangles in a Delaunay mesh nerve either have a common edge or a common vertex with the nerve nucleus.Here, Nerve nucleus means that triangle which has maximum area in a Delaunay mesh.

Comment: OK thank you for the clarification regarding the definition of the nucleus. Please take a look at my answer below.

Comment: Related: [(105201)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105201/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I would say it's not an exact duplicate. The question you mention asks for the polygon with the most adjacent polygons in a mesh; that polygon does not necessarily have to be the one with the largest area.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for your feedback.  My comment was misleading.  I intended it to nudge Odrisso into mentioning that question in this one as I felt that the tools used there would prove useful here.  I'll edit my comment to my plain and standard **Related:** link instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The approach I would take is the following:

1. Clear definitions, load a sample image, find corners in the image using the method you indicated in the OP:

   ```
   Clear[img, points, dm, cells, nerve, nervenucleus]
   img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Aerial2"}];
   points = ImageCorners[img, MaxFeatures -> 200];
   ```
2. **Generate a Delaunay mesh** from those points:

   ```
   dm = DelaunayMesh[
          points, PlotTheme -> "Lines",
          MeshCellStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0.3]], Opacity[0]]
        ];

   Show[img, dm]
   ```

   [image: Mathematica graphics]
3. Extract the **coordinates for the two-dimensional cells** (triangles) that make up the mesh:

   ```
   cells = MeshPrimitives[dm, 2];
   ```
4. Find the "**nucleus**", which you defined as the triangle with the largest area in the mesh:

   ```
   nucleus = First@MaximalBy[cells, Area];
   Show[img, dm, Graphics[{Opacity[0.4], Red, nucleus}]]
   ```

   [image: Mathematica graphics]
5. Find the "**nerve**", that you defined as the set of cells that share a vertex or an edge with the nucleus (note that the nucleus itself is *not* included in this list thanks to the second part of the condition):

   ```
   nerve = Cases[
      cells,
      Polygon[{p1_, p2_, p3_}] /;
       (
        ContainsAny[{p1, p2, p3}, nucleus[[1]] ] && {p1, p2, p3} != nucleus[[1]]
       )
     ];
   ```
6. Show all results:

   ```
   Show[img, dm, Graphics[{Opacity[0.4], Red, nucleus, Darker@Green, nerve}]]
   ```

   [image: Mathematica graphics]