# Finding a Voronoi nerve

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

I have a Voronoi mesh and I need to find a "nerve" which is all the polygons that have common edges with a specific single polygon (a nucleus). Which Mathematica functions can I use?

Comment: See this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164935/9490

Comment: also here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105283/9490

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Henrik Schumacher wrote a very nice answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160443/12) that provides the building blocks for converting a mesh to a graph based on the adjacency of its cells. This is now incorporated into [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM).

Thus, let's build a mesh.

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {50, 2}];

mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts]
```

Load the package.

```
<< IGraphM`
```

Let this be our cell of interest:

```
center = {2, 13};
```

`{2, 13}` means the 13th 2-dimensional cell in the mesh.

Get its adjacent cells, based on the adjacency graph:

```
neigh = AdjacencyList[
  IGMeshCellAdjacencyGraph[mesh, 2],
  center
  ]
(* {{2, 27}, {2, 28}, {2, 43}, {2, 45}, {2, 47}} *)
```

Highlight them:

```
HighlightMesh[mesh, {Style[center, Red], neigh}]
```

[image]

One more ingredient that you might need is matching up the Voronoi cells with their corresponding points:

- [Site - Cell Correspondence in Voronoi Diagram obtained via VoronoiMesh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58395/12)