# How to find point within polygons and connect them

Tags: polygons

I have the following figure:

[image]

Here, I have the following values of 25 image corner-points:

```
a = {{528.5, 563.5}, {282.5, 726.5}, {283.5, 722.5}, {42.5, 
 607.5}, {264.5, 394.5}, {269.5, 322.5}, {360.5, 334.5}, {366.5, 
  375.5}, {239.5, 324.5}, {265.5, 332.5}, {210.5, 326.5}, {366.5, 
   315.5}, {238.5, 394.5}, {195.5, 441.5}, {379.5, 333.5}, {219.5, 
   397.5}, {371.5, 386.5}, {121.5, 635.5}, {350.5, 335.5}, {350.5, 
  386.5}, {291.5, 320.5}, {344.5, 375.5}, {445.5, 310.5}, {342.5, 
  317.5}, {326.5, 390.5}}
```

Then, I calculated the Voronoi mesh polygons for these corner-points. The Voronoimesh polygons are:

```
vm= {Polygon[{{235.086, 434.547}, {123.376, 373.614}, {223.462, 
360.927}}], Polygon[{{293.659, 363.962}, {304.17, 526.888}, {251.5, 
449.564}, {251.5, 363.282}}], 
 Polygon[{{270.045, 206.5}, {281.557, 333.123}, {254.418, 
322.267}, {246.7, 206.5}}], 
Polygon[{{361., 523.5}, {338.104, 386.125}, {355.5, 376.636}, {361., 
384.636}}], 
Polygon[{{117.5, 830.5}, {190.486, 701.371}, {492.956, 
776.989}, {528.413, 830.5}}], 
 Polygon[{{353.98, 562.844}, {492.956, 776.989}, {190.486, 
701.371}, {257.644, 576.318}, {316.267, 557.959}}], 
Polygon[{{354.303, 323.032}, {354.984, 322.311}, {369.628, 
326.935}, {371.047, 353.896}, {357.587, 355.865}}], 
 Polygon[{{428.532, 368.005}, {405.303, 364.499}, {371.047, 
353.896}, {369.628, 326.935}, {405.254, 301.206}}], 
Polygon[{{354.303, 323.032}, {357.587, 355.865}, {355.5, 
356.7}, {315.239, 350.661}, {318.182, 339.086}}], 
Polygon[{{311.529, 354.235}, {315.239, 350.661}, {355.5, 
356.7}, {355.5, 376.636}, {338.104, 386.125}}], 
Polygon[{{345.333, 206.5}, {354.984, 322.311}, {354.303, 
323.032}, {318.182, 339.086}, {310.382, 206.5}}], 
 Polygon[{{-79., 830.5}, {-79., 344.139}, {-72.4138, 
348.076}, {117.025, 522.68}, {7.92405, 830.5}}], 
 Polygon[{{399.259, 206.5}, {405.254, 301.206}, {369.628, 
326.935}, {354.984, 322.311}, {345.333, 206.5}}], 
 Polygon[{{7.92405, 830.5}, {117.025, 522.68}, {257.644, 
 576.318}, {190.486, 701.371}, {117.5, 830.5}}], 
 Polygon[{{246.7, 206.5}, {254.418, 322.267}, {242.944, 
 359.556}, {227.333, 359.333}, {216.793, 206.5}}], 
 Polygon[{{355.5, 376.636}, {355.5, 356.7}, {357.587, 
 355.865}, {371.047, 353.896}, {405.303, 364.499}, {361., 
 384.636}}], 
 Polygon[{{295.094, 362.453}, {293.659, 363.962}, {251.5, 
 363.282}, {242.944, 359.556}, {254.418, 322.267}, {281.557, 
 333.123}}], 
 Polygon[{{235.086, 434.547}, {223.462, 360.927}, {227.333, 
 359.333}, {242.944, 359.556}, {251.5, 363.282}, {251.5, 
 449.564}}], 
 Polygon[{{363.508, 551.719}, {361., 523.5}, {361., 
 384.636}, {405.303, 364.499}, {428.532, 368.005}, {496.269, 
 433.959}}], 
 Polygon[{{650., 206.5}, {650., 383.526}, {496.269, 
 433.959}, {428.532, 368.005}, {405.254, 301.206}, {399.259, 
  206.5}}], 
 Polygon[{{528.413, 830.5}, {492.956, 776.989}, {353.98, 
 562.844}, {363.508, 551.719}, {496.269, 433.959}, {650., 
  383.526}, {650., 830.5}}], 
 Polygon[{{310.382, 206.5}, {318.182, 339.086}, {315.239, 
  350.661}, {311.529, 354.235}, {295.094, 362.453}, {281.557, 
    333.123}, {270.045, 206.5}}], 
  Polygon[{{216.793, 206.5}, {227.333, 359.333}, {223.462, 
  360.927}, {123.376, 373.614}, {-72.4138, 348.076}, {-79., 
  344.139}, {-79., 206.5}}], 
  Polygon[{{316.267, 557.959}, {257.644, 576.318}, {117.025, 
   522.68}, {-72.4138, 348.076}, {123.376, 373.614}, {235.086, 
   434.547}, {251.5, 449.564}, {304.17, 526.888}}], 
   Polygon[{{361., 523.5}, {363.508, 551.719}, {353.98, 
   562.844}, {316.267, 557.959}, {304.17, 526.888}, {293.659, 
   363.962}, {295.094, 362.453}, {311.529, 354.235}, {338.104, 
   386.125}}]}
```

Then, I choose 9 polygons from here. For your convenience, I am only giving the polygon values. The polygons are:

```
  aa = {{{293.659, 363.962}, {304.17, 526.888}, {251.5, 449.564}, {251.5, 
  363.282}}, {{361., 523.5}, {338.104, 386.125}, {355.5, 
  376.636}, {361., 384.636}}, {{353.98, 562.844}, {492.956, 
  776.989}, {190.486, 701.371}, {257.644, 576.318}, {316.267, 
  557.959}}, {{311.529, 354.235}, {315.239, 350.661}, {355.5, 
  356.7}, {355.5, 376.636}, {338.104, 386.125}}, {{295.094, 
  362.453}, {293.659, 363.962}, {251.5, 363.282}, {242.944, 
  359.556}, {254.418, 322.267}, {281.557, 333.123}}, {{363.508, 
  551.719}, {361., 523.5}, {361., 384.636}, {405.303, 
  364.499}, {428.532, 368.005}, {496.269, 433.959}}, {{528.413, 
  830.5}, {492.956, 776.989}, {353.98, 562.844}, {363.508, 
  551.719}, {496.269, 433.959}, {650., 383.526}, {650., 
  830.5}}, {{310.382, 206.5}, {318.182, 339.086}, {315.239, 
  350.661}, {311.529, 354.235}, {295.094, 362.453}, {281.557, 
  333.123}, {270.045, 206.5}}, {{316.267, 557.959}, {257.644, 
  576.318}, {117.025, 522.68}, {-72.4138, 348.076}, {123.376, 
  373.614}, {235.086, 434.547}, {251.5, 449.564}, {304.17, 526.888}}}
```

Now, I want to find the corner-points from "a" which are within the polygons described in aa. Then connect them by a line. So, the final figure would be like this:
[image]

Please let me know, how to do a automatic code of that in mathematica. Thanks.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9405/2079

Comment: Which one? `Graphics /@ Polygon /@ Permutations@RandomInteger[{1, 30}, {6, 2}]`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I don't get it. In the link there are lots of codes there. Should I use " inpolyQ" function that describe in the code?

Comment: You already asked eight questions, never accepted an answer and voted only once. Please be a nice site citizen. Read the following comment

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Hi, Sorry. I didn't know that I have to do that. I always give thanks comment. I voted them all now. and Also accepted the correct answers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Odrisso Well done!

Answer (score 3):

Using the `FindAdjPoly` function presented [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105201/how-to-find-adjacent-polygons-of-a-specific-polygon-in-a-voronoimesh) we can find those cells adjacent to our one of interest. Then we can look back and find the points which were the seeds for those cells (in order thankfully) and simply connect them. I've modified the output of `FindAdjPoly` slightly to keep the rotational ordering. There also may be a more elegant way to retrieve the seed points.

```
    pts = {{528.5, 563.5}, {282.5, 726.5}, {283.5, 722.5}, {42.5, 
      607.5}, {264.5, 394.5}, {269.5, 322.5}, {360.5, 334.5}, {366.5, 
      375.5}, {239.5, 324.5}, {265.5, 332.5}, {210.5, 326.5}, {366.5, 
      315.5}, {238.5, 394.5}, {195.5, 441.5}, {379.5, 333.5}, {219.5, 
      397.5}, {371.5, 386.5}, {121.5, 635.5}, {350.5, 335.5}, {350.5, 
      386.5}, {291.5, 320.5}, {344.5, 375.5}, {445.5, 310.5}, {342.5, 
      317.5}, {326.5, 390.5}};

    FindAdjPoly[ptIndex_, {pts_, Vmesh_}] := 
     Block[{pt, mpt, regs, lines, poly, loc, all}, 
      mpt = MeshCoordinates[Vmesh];
      (*Get the mesh polygons*)regs = MeshCells[Vmesh, 2];
      pt = pts[[ptIndex]];
      (*Select the polygon containing pt*)
      poly = SelectFirst[(regs /. Polygon[a__] :> {a, Polygon@mpt[[a]]}), 
        RegionMember[Last@#, pt] &];
      (*Find the index of the polygon in mesh*)
      loc = MeshCellIndex[Vmesh, {Polygon[First@poly]}][[1, 2]];
      (*Get the edges of the polygon*)

      lines = Partition[First@poly, 2, 1, 1];
      (*Find polygons that share the above edges*)

      all = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[With[{ed = #}, 
            Position[regs /. Polygon[a__] :> (MemberQ[a, #] & /@ ed), 
            {True, True}]] & /@ lines];

      {loc, DeleteCases[all, loc]}
      ]
```

Then

```
    iCell = 25;

    Vmesh = VoronoiMesh[pts];
    {iPoly, polys} = FindAdjPoly[iCell, {pts, Vmesh}];

    mpt = MeshCoordinates[Vmesh];
    regs = MeshCells[Vmesh, 2];
    cpts = Table[
       SelectFirst[pts, RegionMember[(regs[[i]] /. 
     Polygon[a__] :> {a, Polygon@mpt[[a]]})[[2]], #] &], 
    {i, polys}];

    Show[
     HighlightMesh[Vmesh, {{{2, iPoly}}, 
       Transpose[{ConstantArray[2, Length[polys]], polys}]}],
     Graphics[{
       {Blue, Point[pts]},
       {Black, Point[cpts], JoinedCurve[Line[cpts], CurveClosed -> True]}
       }]
     ]
```

[image]

Works for any Voronoi mesh:

```
    pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}];
    iCell = 50;
    ...
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code. But, when I change the points values to 50 instead of 25, it gives error. I changed all 25 to 50 in the code. But, it's still giving error. What should I do?

Comment: You don't have 50 seed points or polygons so of course it can't highlight and ring the 50th one; you only have 25. Curiously the 25th point seemed to be a lucky case where the 25 element in `pts` corresponded to the 25th polygon in `Vmesh`, this is in general not the case and I have amended the code above such that now changing the value of `iCell` will highlight and ring the corresponding polygon correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. Now, I want to change the icell value to the value that hold the maximum adjacent point. I have that index value. But, when I putt that in the code, it gives an error. I found it it's because there is a {} in the value. Here is the code for founding the polygon that held the maximum adjacent points:
        pv = MeshPrimitives[Vmesh, 2]
        numv = Length /@ Level[pv, {2}]
        sv = Max[numv]
        nv = Count[numv, sv]
        index2 = Level[Position[numv, sv], {2}]

Now, this index2 is giving {50}. When I put this, it gives an error. How to solve this?

Comment: If you only care about the cell with the highest number of adjacent polygons you could have put this in you question statement. Anyhow, you should have good for for doing that from this answer to your previous question:
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105216/6588
If your problem is that you have `iCell={50}` instead of `iCell=50` there are many ways of removing the `List` head, as described here:
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109099/strip-tail-out-of-a-list
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19277/splicing-a-list-of-arguments-into-a-function-with-sequence

Comment: `iCell = First@index2`

`iCell = Sequence @@ index2`

`iCell = index2[[1]]`

`iCell = Delete[index2, 0]`